# I want to update table but before update it should check null value

Tags: sql, sql-server

Hi i want to update a table column by concatenating 3 columns value but the problem is how can i stop the update if any of the 3 columns has null value.

my query is given below where i want to update record of ind_ref 123 but if any of the value of the 3 column which i concatenating is null then it shouldn't update the display_name column. How can i achieve it?

```
update individual_loc
Set individual_loc.display_name=individual_loc.address1+','+INDIVIDUAL_LOCATION.TOWN+','+INDIVIDUAL_LOCATION.COUNTY
where individual_loc.ind_ref=123
```

Comment: look for `ISNULL`(sql server specific) or `COALESCE`(standard)

Comment: Skip that column, only store each value once. Create a view instead that also returns the concatenated values.

Comment: can any one help me writing the query, as im new to the sql world and finding abit complex.

Comment: Well, I forgot, SQL Server has computed columns. That's what you want here!

Comment: Don't read the below answers, at least as long they aren't using computed columns!

Comment: thanks alot . i found Hasmukh Viradiya 's answered query did my job. its really helpful . Everyday i learn new things from this group. Thank you evey one.

Comment: And you still don't listen... Your table is not normalized. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
UPDATE  individual_loc
SET     individual_loc.display_name = CASE WHEN ISNULL(individual_loc.address1,
                                                   '') != ''
                                            AND ISNULL(INDIVIDUAL_LOCATION.TOWN,
                                                       '') != ''
                                            AND ISNULL(INDIVIDUAL_LOCATION.COUNTY,
                                                       '') != ''
                                       THEN individual_loc.address1 + ','
                                            + INDIVIDUAL_LOCATION.TOWN
                                            + ','
                                            + INDIVIDUAL_LOCATION.COUNTY
                                       ELSE individual_loc.display_name
                                  END
WHERE   individual_loc.ind_ref = 123
```

Answer (score 3):

Simply add a check for `NULL` in your `WHERE` clause.

```
UPDATE individual_loc
SET display_name = address1 + ',' + TOWN + ',' + COUNTY
WHERE ind_ref = 123 AND address1 IS NOT NULL AND TOWN IS NOT NULL AND COUNTY IS NOT NULL
```

Answer (score 1):

**try this**

```
update individual_loc
Set individual_loc.display_name=individual_loc.address1+','+
    individual_loc.TOWN+','+individual_loc.COUNTY
where individual_loc.ind_ref=123 
AND address1 is not null
AND town is not null
AND county is not null
```

Basically, only perform the update if the fields aren't null

Answer (score 0):

One method is with COALESCE:

```
UPDATE individual_loc
SET individual_loc.display_name=COALESCE(individual_loc.address1+','+INDIVIDUAL_LOCATION.TOWN+','+INDIVIDUAL_LOCATION.COUNTY, individual_loc.display_name)
where individual_loc.ind_ref=123;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also check null values by using `coalesce()` function

```
update individual_loc
Set individual_loc.display_name=individual_loc.address1+','+INDIVIDUAL_LOCATION.TOWN+','+INDIVIDUAL_LOCATION.COUNTY
where individual_loc.ind_ref=123 
and coalesce(individual_loc.address1+','+INDIVIDUAL_LOCATION.TOWN+','+INDIVIDUAL_LOCATION.COUNTY, 0) <> 0
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to avoid null issues just check for isnull(individual_loc.address1,'')

If its something else try :
IIF((isnull(address1,'')='' OR isnull(TOWN,'')='' OR isnull(COUNTY,'')=''), UPDATE STATEMENT, PRINT 'False')